# Coding Practice with Kick Start Session #1 - Kick Start 2022

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I tried solving the [practice question on Google Kickstart](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/00000000008f4332/0000000000942404) and the solution I came up with seems to be wrong [I honestly don't know/understand why]. The question basically asks us to return the number of remaining candy after sharing n number of candy to m children. All children should have the same number of candy and each child must receive maximum number of candy possible.

**Example ( +  thought process) :**
Given 5 bags of candy and 2 children, we have a total of 25 candy where each bag contains 5 candy  (i.e. **5** **5** **5** **5** **5**). Share all the candy in such a way that each child receives the maximum amount of candy and all children receive equal number of candy pieces. We start sharing the candy one child at a time in alternation. by the time both children receive 12 candy each, we'll have only 1 candy left. Since we cannot break one candy into half, we return 1 as the remainder.

**The input is made in this format:**

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, **T. T** test cases follow.

Each test case consists of two lines. The first line of each test case contains two integers: integer **N**, the number of candy bags, and **M**, the number of kids.

The next line contains N non-negative integers **C[0],C[1],…,C[N]** representing array **C**, where the *i-th* integer represents the number of candies in the *i-th* bag.

Here is an example; there are **2** test cases:

```
2
7 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 10
7 7 7 7 7
```

**In the first test case,**  there are **7** bags of candy and **3** children to share the candy amongst. Candy bag 1 has 1 candy, candy bag 2 has 2 candies, candy bag 3 has 3 candies, candy bag 4 has 4 candies, candy bag 5 has 5 candies, candy bag 6 has 6 candies, and candy bag 7 has 7 candies.

**In the second test case,** there are **5** candies and **10** children to share the candy amongst. All 5 candy bags have 7 candies in each.

**The output is expected to be of this format:**

```
Case #1: 1
Case #2: 5
```

**Explanation / Thought process**:

**In the first test case,** there's a grand total of 28 candies. We have to share all 28 equally between 3 children and return what's left as the answer. We can start sharing the candy and we find out that after all the kids have received 9 candies, we are left with 1 candy and we can't share/break/cut the candy into 3 equal (1/3)s so we return 1 as the answer to the first test case.

**In the second test case,** there is a grand total of 35 candies. We have to share all 35 candies equally between 10 children. After giving each child up to just 3 candies, we find out that we have only 5 candies left and we cannot share/break/cut up 5 candies to share amongst 10 children, hence we return 5 as the answer to the second test case.

**This is my code (in Python 3)**

```
num_testcases = int(input())
for etc in range(num_testcases):
    n, m =  map(int, input().split())
    candies = input().split()
    candies_arr = [int(i) for i in candies]
    result = sum(candies_arr)  % m
    print('#Case {}: {}'.format(etc+1, result))
```

I would really like to learn/understand why my code isn't accepted as the correct answer. I probably must have underestimated the difficulty of the question and my thought process may be wrong. Thank you all for your time and I hope a favourable reply.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is incorrectly formatted.

This is what you're using:

```py
print('#Case {}: {}'.format(etc+1, result))
```

What you actually need to use:

```py
print('Case #{}: {}'.format(etc+1, result))
```

Comment: ‍♂️..... Thanks! I'm stunned that I can still make such glaring mistakes. I'll be far more careful next time. Thanks again!